# How can I add TextView horizontally?

Tags: java, android, textview, tablelayout

I am new in programming android, and I'm developing a BattleShip game . I created a 10x10 board , and now I'm trying to add the random ships on the board. I found the positions through the getPositionOfTag , and through it completed the ship with another textview with vertical orientation . I wonder how I put more textviews the ship in order to supplement it with its true size ( 5 squares). And also like to know how to put it ramdom horizontally.

Java Code:

```js
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho_tabuleiro; i++) {

            tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

            for (int j = 0; j < tamanho_tabuleiro; j++) {


                textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);

                textView.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
                //textView.setText(" ");
                textView.getLayoutParams().height = lado_quadrado;
                textView.getLayoutParams().width = lado_quadrado;
                textView.setTag(String.valueOf(i + "." + j));

                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        v.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);
                    }
                });

                tableRow.addView(textView);
            }

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow, tableParams);
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < qtd_portaAvioes; k++) {

            Random random = new Random();

            int indexI = random.nextInt(tamanho_tabuleiro);
            int indexJ = random.nextInt(tamanho_tabuleiro);

            TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(indexI);

            View view = tableRow.findViewWithTag(indexI + "." + indexJ );

            if (view != null && !verificaPopulado(view)) {
                int positionComeco = getPositionOfTag((String) view.getTag());
                    addNavio(tableRow, new PortaAvioes(this), positionComeco);

                int orientation = random.nextInt(2);

                for(int x = 0; x < tam_portaAvioes; x++) {

                    TableRow tableRow1 = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(indexI + 1);

                    if (orientation == 0) {
                    //verificar sea a tablerow existe, se nao esta acima do limite
                        if (tableRow1 != null) {
                            View view2 = tableRow1.findViewWithTag(indexI + 1 + "." + positionComeco);

                            if (view2 != null && !verificaPopulado(view2)) {
                                addNavio(tableRow1, new PortaAvioes(this), positionComeco);
                            }
                        } else {
                            View view2 = tableRow1.findViewWithTag(indexI + 1 + "." + positionComeco);
                        }
                    }else if (orientation == 1) {
                        //add ship horizontal
                    }
                }
            }
        }


public void addNavio(TableRow tableRow, TextView navio, int position) {
        tableRow.removeViewAt(position);
        tableRow.addView(navio, position);
    }

    public boolean verificaPopulado(View view) {
        if (view instanceof Encouracado || view instanceof Destroyer || view instanceof PortaAvioes || view instanceof Cruiser || view instanceof Submarino)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public int getPositionOfTag(String tag) {
        return Integer.parseInt(tag.substring(tag.indexOf(".") + 1));
    }
```

PortaAvioes Class:

```js
public class PortaAvioes extends TextView {
    

    public PortaAvioes(Context context) {
        super(context);

        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);
        gd.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            setText("PA");
            setBackground(gd);
        } else
            setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

Comment: use textview width=10dp height=fill parent

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  RotateAnimation rotateAnmi = (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.drawable.rorate);
> rotateTv.setAnimation(rotateAnmi);      
>    rotateTv.setGravity(Gravity.AXIS_X_SHIFT);
>     rotateTv.setText();
> ```